# How do I know who I haven't met?

Tags: stardew-valley

I know I have to introduce myself to 28 people, but I feel like I've run out of people! How do I know who I haven't met? Or is it all just sort of hit and miss til I bump into everyone?

Comment: You can only go off of their portrait and the '???' I'm afraid.

Answer (score 7):

You won't know who you haven't met but you can know who you **have** met by checking your social tab (Start Menu -> Heart Icon). Anybody you have not met has a filled-in portrait (that helps with identification) and ??? for a name.

Comment: From my experience, despite not meeting them, they still have a portrait.

Comment: I don't remember now. I am not home I know I had the ??? names but I could have sworn they had a blank portrait. Unless you just need to see them to get the portrait.

Comment: That might be true. What qualifies as meeting them - conversing?

Comment: Yea I am 99% sure you must talk to them to count as introduced. (I also might just be wrong about the portrait thing) It would be very interesting if I am not though haha.

Comment: Can confirm. They have ??? for a name, but they do have a portrait. It was useful for me to track people I'd met this way, and is how I managed to meet everyone.

Comment: Yup, I can confirm what Flutter says, their names will show up as ???? but you can still see their sprites, which actually helps as you can identify who you haven't spoken to yet and look for them without talking to everyone unnecessarily.